# rebuild my screen with future provider for specific widgets using id root

Tags: android, flutter, rest, flutter-futurebuilder

im trying to retrieve tasks from project in another words i want to rebuild my screen on viewing tasks with specific forgin key projectId i got this error while working on future provider
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4SY1.png)

those are api/method/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvO5X.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kBl8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktm8D.png)

here i want to view tasks only when i pass projectId

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project/model/task_model.dart';
import 'package:project/project_dtetailForTest.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'new_project.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
class  TaskById extends StatefulWidget {
  //const TaskById({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  final int project_id;
  final Task task =Task();
  TaskById({required this.project_id}):super();
  @override
  State<TaskById> createState() => _TaskByIdState();
}

class _TaskByIdState extends State<TaskById> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final taskP= Provider.of<TaskProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
        child: Container(
         color: const Color(0xff94adb4),
         height: 2,
         width: 320,
      ),
      preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(4.0)),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor:const Color(0xff076792),
        title: const Text(
          'Project1',
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
             fontSize: 35,
             fontWeight:FontWeight.w700,
             shadows: [
               Shadow(
                  color: Color(0xa6A2B6D4),
                  blurRadius:20),
              ] ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            size: 44,
          ),
        ),
       actions:[Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 6, 3),
         child: IconButton(
            color:Colors.white ,
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.search,
              size: 44,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
       ),] 
      ),//TaskProvider(){
  //   this.fetchTask();
  // }


      body: FutureProvider(
        create: (context) => TaskProvider().fetchTask() ,
        initialData:  [CircularProgressIndicator()],
        child:Center(child: Consumer<Task>( 
          builder: (context, task, widget) {
            return (taskP !=null) ? Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children:  const [
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
               child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24,10,10,8),
                child: Text('Project1',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff076792),
                  fontSize: 40,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                ),
                ),
               ),
              ),              
            ],
          ),
          // dynamic list
         Expanded(
           child: ListView.builder(
           itemCount: taskP.task.length ,
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
             return  Padding(
            padding:  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(28, 12, 28, 0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
               
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => projectDetails()));
              },
               child: Card(child:Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18,8,9,4),
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(19.0),
                  color: const Color(0xff076792),
                  boxShadow:  const [
                  BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, spreadRadius: 1),
                  BoxShadow(color: Color(0xa6A2B6D4),               
                     offset: Offset(7,5),
                     blurRadius:20),
                  ],
                  ),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('Starting '+taskP.task[index].start.toString(),style:
                        const TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 133, 186, 202),fontSize: 18,),
                       ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                  Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(taskP.task[index].title??'',style:
                       const TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 34,)),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                  Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text('Ending '+taskP.task[index].end.toString(),style:
                       const TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 133, 186, 202),
                       fontSize: 18,
                       )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ]),
              ),),
            ),
          );
           }),
         )
         ],
      )
            : CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ) ,
        
        ) 
    //         widget.project_id),
          
    //       builder: (context, snapshot){
    //         if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
    //         return snapshot.hasData
    //             ? TaskList(taskP: snapshot.data)
    //             : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    //       }),
    )
    ); 
  }
}
```

here how i pass projectId

```
 onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TaskById(project_id: projectP.project[index].id!,)));
              },
```

here the api , model,

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final task = taskFromJson(jsonString);
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

//List<Task> taskFromJson(String str) => List<Task>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Task.fromJson(x)));

//String taskToJson(List<Task> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Task {
  String? url;
  int? id;
  String? owner;
  String? project;
  String? title;
  DateTime? start;
  DateTime? end;
  String? desc;
  int? project_id;

  Task(
      {this.url,
      this.id,
      this.owner,
      this.project,
      this.title,
      this.start,
      this.end,
      this.desc,
      this.project_id});

  
  factory Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Task(
    url :json["url"],
    id: json["id"],
    owner: json["owner"],
    project: json["project"],
    title: json["title"],
    start: DateTime.parse(json["start"]),
    end: DateTime.parse(json["end"]),
    desc: json["desc"],
    project_id: json["project_id"],
    
    
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "url": url,
    "id": id,
    "owner": owner,
    "project": project, 
    "title": title,
    "start": start?.toIso8601String(),
    "end": end?.toIso8601String(),
    "desc": desc,
    "project_id": project_id,
  };
}
class TaskProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  TaskProvider(){
    this.fetchTask();
  }


  List<Task> _task = [];
  List<Task> get task {
    return [..._task];
  }

    void addTask(Task task) async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('http://mostafahamed.pythonanywhere.com/project/task'),
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: json.encode(task));
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      task.id = json.decode(response.body)['id'];
      _task.add(task);
      notifyListeners();
      print('suceeed add ed task');
      print(response.body);
    }else{
      print(response.body);
       print('failed add ed task');
    }
  }

  void deleteTask(Task task) async {
    final response =
        await http.delete(Uri.parse('http://mostafahamed.pythonanywhere.com/project/task${task.id}/'));
    if (response.statusCode == 204) {
      _task.remove(task);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }


     Future fetchTask([project_id]) async{
     final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('http://mostafahamed.pythonanywhere.com/tasks/?format=json'));
    if (response.statusCode==200){
      var data = json.decode(response.body)as List;
      _task=data.map<Task>((json) => Task.fromJson(json)).toList();
      
      
      notifyListeners();
       print('sucess view list');
       return _task;
    }
   else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load tasks');
  }
  }
}
```

the error i got when i click on a project wiget to diplay its tasks on new screen

```
 The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Consumer<Task>(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Task> above this Consumer<Task> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Consumer<Task> is under your MultiProvider/Provider<Task>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }


  consider using `builder` like so:

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
```

Comment: please dont use image for code, try to copy paste or type it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.